# Manifolds with special holonomy especially $G_2$

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, holonomy

I am interested in learning about $G_2$ manifolds and am aware that one of the canonical references is Joyce's Compact Manifolds with Special Holonomy.  I am certain that my background is, at this moment, not enough to read this research monograph so I would like to know if there are books that can bring me up to speed.  My background is in Lee and Do Carmo level.

Comment: There are currently ongoing efforts on the classification of G2 manifolds. [These slides](http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/gf2016/haskins_1.pdf) seem to give a nice introductory overview of the subject. Here are a few papers on [new invariants and the likes](http://opus.bath.ac.uk/44702/1/bord_gnt_accepted.pdf). From here googling the authors should bring up more resources and eventually some books.

Answer (score 10):

Joyce's book *Riemannian Holonomy Groups and Calibrated Geometry* is an extended version of the research monograph you are reading, with more details and background material, aimed at providing a graduate course in the subject.

Answer (score 4):

Salamon's *Riemannian geometry and holonomy groups* is another nice place to start.

Comment: http://calvino.polito.it/~salamon/G/rghg.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I started with this 58 page set of notes by Joyce https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0108088.pdf, it was published as the first section of a three section book "Calabi-Yau Manifolds and Related Geometries" (the other two sections were written by Gross and Huybrechts). This is lighter than his textbooks.

I also recommend this introductory talk of Robert Bryant https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j0qBv62pNWw.